# Status Bar Hides The Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am developing an iOS application where I am streaming a live video from youtube. After exiting the full-screen mode the status bar overlays the navigation bar in all views ([as seen in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeLC5.png))

I have searched for this problem and found a solution which is adding the following code in a function that is executed after exiting the full-screen mode:

```
   @objc func videoExitFullScreen (_ sender: Any?){
         navBar.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20)
   }
```

This code successfully solved the problem. However, I need to place this code in every controller of my application. When I tried to place it in the app delegate as the following it did not solve the problem:

```
   @objc func videoExitFullScreen (_ sender: Any?){
         UINavigationBar.appearance().frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20)
   }
```

Do you have any suggestions where I can place the code in one place and it will solve the problem?

Comment: create a baseViewController and put inside the viewWillAppear methods, it will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

// create a new class of type UIViewController

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.videoExitFullScreen()
    }

    func videoExitFullScreen (){
        navBar.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20)
    }
}
```

// replace UIViewController to BaseViewController

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work :( .. I think the problem in this statement         UINavigationBar.appearance().frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20). When I drag the navigation bar from the story board and use this navBar.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20) it works .. How would I generate this on all

Comment: @shadenalsubaiheen is viewWillappear called after exiting the full-screen mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use Auto Layout and pin your view to Top Layout Guide, or use the new Safe Area Layout Guides. To enable it, in your storyboard's File inspector tick the following option.[image]